# Fixed width div pushes floated text off the screen

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wayP/

```
<div style="position:fixed;width:100%;">
    <p style="float:right;">Hello World</p>
</div>
```

What gives?  Is there a clean way to ensure this doesn't happen?  Or is it just margin-right til it looks acceptable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4wayP/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to specify `top: 0; left: 0`.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wayP/3/)

Otherwise it will be placed whereever it would be if it had `position: static`. In your case, the body has default margin, so it would be placed according to that margin.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wayP/4/) will help illustrate what happened actually.